# Add comments on user profile

Tags: users

How do you add a comment form on your user profile in Drupal 7? I have installed panels but I don't know how you add the comment form on the users profile

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the user profile is not a type of "node" so it is invisible to Panels.  Therefore, you will most likely need to write a custom module that will inject the comment form into the user's profile page.

Comment: any other alternatives? cause I'm not a programmer

Comment: If I knew of a module that could do this, then I would tell you because I try to avoid writing my custom modules.  There is another thread (http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11526/how-do-enable-comments-for-user-profile) that suggests using profile2 module, but I recently tried it (and submitted a critical bug) where disabling it brings down your entire site (white screen of death).

Comment: ok I'm using profile2 module. What I don't understand is how do you attach it to user profile in views?

Answer (score 1):

I've created a "guestbook" type content type with a user [reference](http://drupal.org/project/references) to the user. That content type has comments enabled. Then using the [prepopulate](http://drupal.org/project/prepopulate) module I pass the username to the "node add" page which looks like this:

```
node/add/guestbook?edit[field_guestbook_userreference][und][0][uid]=USERNAME
```

Then use a view to display the guestbook nodes on a user profile with links to see the comments.

If you use the [profile2](http://drupal.org/project/profile2) module (which turns user profiles into nodes) then you can probably just enable comments to get your "profile comments".

You might also want to checkout the [guestbook](http://drupal.org/project/guestbook) module, there has been some recent development for the D7 dev version.

Comment: I don't see an option to enable comments in profile2 module. I went Home > Administration > Structure > Profile types

Comment: sorry, looks like that's not possible after all. I saw your questions in the profile2 issue queue, please update here if you get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Disqus module](http://drupal.org/project/disqus), which says that you can add comments either on node or to user:

> Drupal Integration
>
> - Display recent comments, popular threads, and other widgets in blocks
> - Provide comments on any node type or user
> - Views 2/3 integration (number of comments)
> - Single Sign-On

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate question, have a look at this [post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11526/how-do-i-enable-comments-for-user-profiles), I went for [user profile comments module](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_profile_comments)

EDIT:
[user profile comments works module](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_profile_comments) works fine out of the box, but has a lot of 'missing features', not recognized by: panels, features, views, i18n, etc. if you don`t need those, go for it.

Inspired by @moto-Tribe answer I solved like this:

You'll need: (modules) views, panels, rules, entity reference and entity reference prepopulate.

1.- Make a contentype named:user_comments, remove body field. Comments will be node title (255 Maximum length). Add a entity reference field (field_user_reference_comments)

2.- Make a USER view (user_comments), add relationship to "entity reference". In contextual filter add : User Uid->provide a defauld value:user id from url.

3.- Inside view make 2 blocks (I did content panes) First block: add UID field, rewrite results: `<a class="" href="/node/add/user-comments?field_user_reference_comments=[uid]">Add comment</a>`; Second block: add content title field usig the relationship. add more relations and fiedls as needed.

4.-Add a new rule (import from here, make sure follow syntax explainded above): `{ "rules_redirect_on_add_a_user_comment" : {
    "LABEL" : "redirect on add a user comment",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "TAGS" : [ "user account" ],
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "ON" : {
      "node_insert--user_comments" : { "bundle" : "user_comments" },
      "node_update--user_comments" : { "bundle" : "user_comments" }
    },
    "DO" : [
      { "redirect" : { "url" : "users\/[node:field_user_reference_comments]" } }
    ]
  }
}`

5.- Enable from panels "user-view". Add user being viewd, add views FIRST BOLKC, add Second block.

6.- You are done, works perfect.