# Comments on users?

Tags: 7, users, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do enable comments for user profile?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11526/how-do-enable-comments-for-user-profile)

What is a good way to allow commenting on users in Drupal 7? I am not keen on making a node per user like in D6. http://drupal.org/sandbox/swentel/1160452 this project looks like abandoned.

Comment: Have you seen http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11526/how-do-enable-comments-for-user-profile?