# How to attach node to user profile?

Tags: 7, nodes, users

How can I attach a node to a user profile with [profile 2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2) (or some other way)? It says [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11526/how-do-i-enable-comments-for-user-profiles) that it is possible but it does not say how.

Comment: ask the same user @Nikit as comment to his answer..Probably he can guide through entire roadmap.. Have you checked this https://drupal.org/project/reply ?

Comment: I installed reply but I don't know how to work with it.no reply button anywhere.Anyway I want nodes for profile.it must be a good thing.I'm new to drupal so many things I dont't understand.Iil try askin Nikit but I don't think h will answer-the question is 1 year old. .thanks

Comment: no add comment button on that question.can someone answer here?

Answer (score 2):

You could add an entity_reference field to the profile and reference the node in that field.

Answer (score 0):

Please read [documentation](https://drupal.org/node/1074296) of this module. Another [doc](http://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/profile2/) googled. [Screencast](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jPbazpRCwP0).

About [Profile2](https://drupal.org/project/profile2) module: As described in the [documentation](http://drupal.org/node/874026) Drupal 7 allows adding fields to user account pages - what serves as simple way for building user profiles. The main differences between that and profile2 are:

- With profile2 user account settings and user profiles are conceptually different things, e.g. with the "Profile pages" module enabled users get two separate menu links "My account" and "My profile".
- Profile2 allows for creating multiple profile types, which may be assigned to roles via permissions (e.g. a general profile + a customer profile)
- Profile2 supports private profile fields, which are only shown to the user owning the profile and to administrators.